# Extensão de arquivo em base64

Tags: php, base64

Estou fazendo um serviço REST e preciso receber uma imagem por base64, só que a imagem pode vir com qualquer extensão, como `jpg`, `png`, `gif`, etc. Como identificar essa extensão e proceder com a gravação?

O código está desse jeito:

```
file_put_contents('img/nome_arquivo.jpg', base64_decode($string)); //Considerando estar recebendo jpg
```

Comment: `base64_decode($string)` da onde vem esse valor?

Comment: É a imagem recebida através do serviço, ela vem codificada com o base64_encode

Comment: Então, se você fala se ele vem com o tipo fica simples resolver seu problema!, porque, o base64_encode não gera o mime-type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagens em base 64 vem com um padrão: `"data:image/gif;base64,....."`, você pode pegar a partir do primeiro `/` até o primeiro `;`.

**Exemplo**:

```
$imgBase64 = "data:image/gif;base64,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";

function getB64Type($str) {
   return substr($str, 11, strpos($str, ';') - 11);
}

var_dump(getB64Type($imgBase64));  // Saída = gif
```

Se você estiver gravando sem o mime type você pode passar a gravar assim:

```
$path = 'imagem_qualquer.png';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data); // gera base64 com mime type

var_dump($base64); // Agora pode grava-lá no db.
```

Comment: Cara, muito bom, consegui resolver assim, ela está vindo com  o mime type sim, valeu

Answer (score 0):

Use a função [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$string = "data:image/gif;base64, ....";

$baseImagem = base64_decode($string);
$extensao =  pathinfo($baseImagem, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$arquivo  =  '';

switch ($extensao) {
    case 'jpg': $arquivo = 'img/nome_arquivo.jpg'; break;
    case 'png': $arquivo = 'img/nome_arquivo.png'; break;
    case 'gif': $arquivo = 'img/nome_arquivo.gif'; break;

    default:
        echo 'Extensão desconhecida!';
        // Aqui você pode definir um arquivo padrão
        break;
}

if ($arquivo !== '') {
    // Proceder com a gravação, use $arquivo
}
```

Comment: Boa amigo, funciona com arquivos que eu conheço o caminho, mas não conseguiu mostrar a extensão da imagem recebida codificada em base64.

Comment: @IsaiasLima Pode mostrar um exemplo de como vem essa imagem em base64?

Comment: Então, o base64_encode transforma uma imagem em uma string, e nos meus testes essa string deu uns 45296 caracteres, e quando eu uso o base64_decode essa string é transformada novamente em uma imagem, só não estou conseguindo identificar a extensão dessa imagem pra eu poder salvar com o "file_put_contents"

Comment: @IsaiasLima Tem como confirmar se usando o `base64_decode` no `pathinfo` como está na resposta funciona? qualquer coisa arrumo ou deleto a resposta. :D